# Adventure works date and random time concat from existing table but getting same value for each row

Tags: sql-server, datetime

executing a function in cmd line query expecting a different time for each row in adventure works

```
select concat(convert(varchar, OrderDate, 101),' ',format(FLOOR(RAND()*(23-0+0))+0,'00'),':',format(FLOOR(RAND()*(59-0+0))+0 ,'00'),':',format(FLOOR(RAND()*(59-0+0))+0,'00'))
from sales.salesorderheader soh

result
05/31/2011 03:36:09
05/31/2011 03:36:09
05/31/2011 03:36:09
05/31/2011 03:36:09
05/31/2011 03:36:09
05/31/2011 03:36:09

expecting
 orderdate:31/05/2011 08:25:56 @newtime:19:57:27 order id :43668
 orderdate:31/05/2011 08:25:56 @newtime:20:08:04 order id :43669
 orderdate:31/05/2011 08:25:56 @newtime:09:06:01 order id :43670
 orderdate:31/05/2011 08:25:56 @newtime:07:09:51 order id :43671
 orderdate:31/05/2011 08:25:56 @newtime:03:32:39 order id :43672
```

is there a fix for this?

Comment: Why would you expect a different time for each row? As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results."*

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is an approach where we convert the datetime to a float and add a random decimal for the time portion.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Orderdate datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('2021-11-26 9:33')
,('2021-11-26 10:15')


Select OrderDate
      ,RandomTime = convert(datetime,
                            floor(convert(float,OrderDate))
                            +(abs(convert(bigint,hashbytes('md5',concat('',newid()))) / 100000.0 )) % 1
                           )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
OrderDate                 RandomTime
2021-11-26 09:33:00.000   2021-11-26 17:19:22.653  -- random time
2021-11-26 10:15:00.000   2021-11-26 05:27:41.440  -- random time
```